# How to bind centered text under two images that are next to each other

Tags: html, css

So I made this
[image]
But the code looks like this

```
<img src="images/kinz/pitou.png" style="width:230px;margin-left:30px;border-style:solid; border-color:rgb(246, 111, 225);" alt="">
<img src="images/kinz/madeline.png" style="width:230px;margin-left:30px;border-style:solid; border-color:rgb(246, 111, 225);" alt="">
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<b>Neferpitou</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<b>Madeline</b>
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i>Hunter x Hunter</i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i>Celeste</i>
```

I need to figure out to have the same result as above but in a way that isn't awful.

I tried using a table but I couldn't get the text to line up nicely under each image, and if I was able to get it lined up under one, the second table would be below the first and not next to it. I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense. I also tried doing`<table> <tr><td>Neferpitou</td><td>Madeline</td></tr></table>` but using border-spacing to try and line them up didn't work very well. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) on a parent container with the images and text in separate containers, and styling the text with the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class.

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.container img {
  width: 230px;
  /* margin-left: 30px; */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(246, 111, 225);
}

div.container p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.container p:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/230?text=pitou.png" alt="">
    <p>Neferpitou</p>
    <p>Hunter x Hunter</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/230?text=madeline.png" alt="">
    <p>Madeline</p>
    <p>Celeste</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example demonstrates using [Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) on a parent container and styling the text with the [adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```css
div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.container img {
  width: 230px;
  /* margin-left: 30px; */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(246, 111, 225);
}

div.container img + p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.container p + p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/230?text=pitou.png" alt="">
  <p>Neferpitou</p>
  <p>Hunter x Hunter</p>

  <img src="https://placehold.co/230?text=madeline.png" alt="">
  <p>Madeline</p>
  <p>Celeste</p>
</div>
```